# What to do when product range evolves and site name does not reflect this?

Tags: seo, domains, marketing, ranking, change-management

Suppose, just as an example, I have a website with domain www.gifts-for-dogs.com.....but after a few years I start selling stuff for Cats and Fish.  I may not keep enough of a range of products for these other type of pets yet, so can't justify changing the domain name and logo (to something like gifts-for-pets.com) just yet....but envisage that I eventually may have to in the not too distant future.

What would be a good strategy here and what are the steps I would have to consider before making these changes?

Answer (score 1):

Your existing customers will know that you sell more than dog gifts but new customers will be confused or might scratch their heads.

I mean zappos started out selling shoes and now they sell more than shoes but their domain name is not as specific as yours.

The best thing I think you can do is while keeping the same site start another site with a new domain. And to market the new site include a banner in your dog site and let people know that you are partners/sister site. Just build up the new site on the shoulder of the dog site.

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Get a new website (gifts-for-pets.com say). Create some sub-domains (or simply pages if you want):

dogs.gifts-for-pets.com   (or gifts-for-pets.com/dogs)

cats.gifts-for-pets.com  (or gifts-for-pets.com/cats)

etc

Redirect (301) www.gifts-for-dogs.com  to  dogs.gifts-for-pets.com  so your SEO for existing site remains intact.

Comment: Just to confirm.  With a Redirect (301), when a person types dogs.gifts-for-pets.com, their browser will actually show whatever is on the server mapped to 'gifts-for-dogs.com' but their domain will just show as dogs.gifts-for-pets.com?

Answer (score 1):

Sub domain also consider like a mini site. I suggest you to create categories for new new stuff. Name internal web page using your keywords and promote those urls. I am sure you won't be needed new domain or sub domains.